# jQCloud How to Use fontsize Property as Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, word-cloud

As per jQCloud's [documentation](http://mistic100.github.io/jQCloud/), fontsize can be set in three ways.

1. array
2. object
3. function

I want to know how to set fontsize using a function. I'm new to jQCloud and cannot find any example with that function approach.

Actually I want font size of words to be responsive. By default the font size is fixed based on 10 steps on all resolutions or windows-sizes. I wonder if this functional approach could be helpful to achieve responsiveness.

Any hint or solution will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you see: *A function taking the container width, the container height and a step number as parameters and returning a valid CSS font size*?

Comment: Yes, I did. But how can I call it. I mean what would be the syntax. I know the container's size but what would be the step number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help @Rory and @Twisty and with some minor tweaks I'm able to resolve the issue by defining the function as follows:

```
$element.jQCloud(word_list, {
  fontSize: function (width, height, step) {
    if (step == 1)
       return width * 0.02 * step + 'px';

    return width * 0.01 * step + 'px';
  },
  delayedMode: false, 
  autoResize: true, 
  height: $element.parent("div").height(), 
  width: $element.parent("div").width() 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation it states:

> A function taking the container width, the container height and a step number as parameters and returning a valid CSS font size

Therefore you can provide a function which accepts those parameters and returns the font size to be used. For example:

```
$('#keywords').jQCloud(words, {
  fontSize: function(width, height, step) {
    return (width / 2 * step) + 'px';
  }
});
```

That will most likely give you massive fonts, but the point is to make the logic clear. You can easily tweak the output to match your needs

Comment: Thank you guys I appreciate your feedback. I'll be posting answer that worked for my scenario.